# Is there a way to access a local variable defined inside a block outside the block?

Tags: ruby

I have written a simple code that evaluates a piece of code and writes the output to a file. In that way it reduces some of my because I need lots and lots of files with return values inside them for every line!.

Anyways, the code I am working with is:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

def create(file, code)
    f = code.strip.each_line.map { |cd| cd.strip.then { |c| [c, "# => #{binding.eval(c)}"] } }
    max_length = f.map { |x| x[0].length }.max + 4
    f.map { |v| v[0].ljust(max_length) << v[1] }.join("\n").tap { |data| File.write(file, data + "\n") }
end

puts create(
    File.join(__dir__, 'p.rb'),
    <<~'EOF'
        foo = 1
        bar = 2
        baz, qux = 5, 3
    EOF
)
```

In this case, the file p.rb is written. The content of p.rb is:

```
foo = 1            # => 1
bar = 2            # => 2
baz, qux = 5, 3    # => [5, 3]
```

But the problem occurs when I want the value of a variable.
For example:

```
puts create(
    File.join(__dir__, 'p.rb'),
    <<~'EOF'
        baz, qux = 5, 3
        [baz, qux]
    EOF
)
```

Output:

```
/tmp/aa.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in create': undefined local variable or method `baz' for main:Object (NameError)
    from /tmp/aa.rb:4:in `eval'
    from /tmp/aa.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in create'
    from /tmp/aa.rb:4:in `then'
    from /tmp/aa.rb:4:in `block in create'
    from /tmp/aa.rb:4:in `each_line'
    from /tmp/aa.rb:4:in `each'
    from /tmp/aa.rb:4:in `map'
    from /tmp/aa.rb:4:in `create'
    from /tmp/aa.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

Previously I worked in some graphical games that also does this kind of thing after reading a configuration file, but there, I used to define the variables as either global variables (just append $ before variable declaration) or just use instance variables on top self object.

But is there a way to get around the problem I am currently facing? Can I define the variables in binding or some hacks like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`binding` returns a new instance every time you call it. You have to send `eval` to the same binding in order to access local variables that you've created earlier:

```
def create(code, b = binding)
  width = code.each_line.map(&:length).max
  code.each_line.map do |line|
    '%-*s   #=> %s' % [width, line.chomp, b.eval(line)]
  end
end

puts create <<~'RUBY'
  baz, qux = 5, 3
  baz
  qux
RUBY
```

Output:

```
baz, qux = 5, 3    #=> [5, 3]
baz                #=> 5
qux                #=> 3
```

Note that in the above example, `binding` will make the method's local variables available to the block:

```
create 'local_variables'
#=> ["local_variables   #=> [:code, :b, :width]"]
```

You might want to create a more restricted evaluation context, e.g. (replicating Ruby's main)

```
def empty_binding
  Object.allocate.instance_eval do
    class << self
      def to_s
        'main'
      end
      alias inspect to_s
    end
    return binding
  end
end

def create(code, b = empty_binding)
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Oh anyways, you don't want to assign variable name b to binding, because later on you will replace it if you have to assign a variable b to your program. I have named it __binding__, which the programmer won't likely to assign!

Comment: @S.Goswami did you see my last example with `empty_binding`? It gives you a binding without any local variables.